# Xamarin Android Binding Library org.apache issue

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

original Android Jar library file (mposlitesdk.jar) has inside this subfolders content:

- com (which has inside subfolder "ingenico" and "zebra")
- META-INF
- org (which has inside subfolder "apache" with subfolder "commons" and "http")

Library is compiled with target 23 (Android 6.0).

Library mposlitesdk.jar is defined (as usually) as embedded jar

Compiler gives me:

- J2XA006 warnings about org.apache.http package which is inside the
  library

> 1>JARTOXML : warning J2XA006: missing class error was raised while
>   reflecting com.ingenico.pclutilities.PclUtilities :
>   com/hoho/android/usbserial/driver/UsbSerialPort 1>JARTOXML : warning
>   J2XA006: missing class error was raised while reflecting
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector :
>   org/apache/commons/logging/Log 1>JARTOXML : warning J2XA006: missing
>   class error was raised while reflecting
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpAuthenticator :
>   org/apache/commons/logging/Log 1>JARTOXML : warning J2XA006: missing
>   class error was raised while reflecting
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.ehcache.EhcacheHttpCacheStorage :
>   net/sf/ehcache/Ehcache 1>JARTOXML : warning J2XA006: missing class
>   error was raised while reflecting
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.memcached.MemcachedHttpCacheStorage
>   : net/spy/memcached/OperationTimeoutException 1>JARTOXML : warning
>   J2XA006: missing class error was raised while reflecting
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.HttpConnPool :
>   org/apache/commons/logging/Log 1>JARTOXML : warning J2XA006: missing
>   class error was raised while reflecting
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.HttpPoolEntry :
>   org/apache/commons/logging/Log 1>JARTOXML : warning J2XA006: missing
>   class error was raised while reflecting org.apache.http.impl.conn.Wire
>   : org/apache/commons/logging/Log 1>JARTOXML : warning J2XA006: missing
>   class error was raised while reflecting
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager :
>   org/apache/commons/logging/Log

- strange invalid tokens with char ' are added to generated sources:

> obj\Debug\generated\src\Org.Apache.Http.Impl.Client.AbstractAuthenticationHandler.cs(244,65,244,66):
>   error CS1519: Il token '`' nella dichiarazione del membro di classe,
>   struttura o interfaccia non è valido

Maybe main issue is about org.apache.http which is duplicated in Xamarin Android namespace?

Thanks for any suggestion
Log is attached

Answer (score 2):

The issue at hand from first glance is that `org.apache.http` is not playing nicely under API 23. Here's why:

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client

Google removed `org.apache.http` and moved it to an `optional` library. What does that mean for Xamarin.Android? Well it means that it is no longer bound in API 23 since Google doesn't ship it with `android.jar`. Thus there's a couple workarounds that you can go about:

1) Use any API level between 9-22 (Xamarin.Android will have bindings for this)

2) Add the `org.apache.http.legacy.jar` to your Binding project as a `ReferenceJar` if you want to satisfy dependencies and not create C# bindings for it. Or use `EmbeddedReferenceJar` if you want to embed the .jar and create C# bindings for it.

You can find this `.jar` in the following location:

`android-sdk\platforms\android-23\optional` (Or any API level above 23 like API 24/etc will have it)